# Streaming Microphone from Javascript to Java. Unable to convert float 32 array to audio file

Tags: java, spring-boot, audio-streaming, java-websocket, javascript-audio-api

I am streaming the audio from microphone using javascript and sending the audio stream from frontend to backend via websocket. In my websocket handle message i can see float array recieving from front end but as soon as i write the float array to a file it does contatin any audio. here is link of generated [audio file](https://file.io/D94taHwci1O4).

```
@Override
    public void handleMessage(WebSocketSession session, WebSocketMessage<?> message) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        byte [] bb =getByteArrayFromByteBuffer((ByteBuffer)message.getPayload());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bb));
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file,bb,true);
    }

private static byte[] getByteArrayFromByteBuffer(ByteBuffer byteBuffer) {
        byte[] bytesArray = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];
        byteBuffer.get(bytesArray, 0, bytesArray.length);
        return bytesArray;
    }
```

[image]

below is javascript streaming code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="stop()">stop</button>

<script>
const AudioContext = window.AudioContext// Safari and old versions of Chrome
var context;
var source;
var bufferDetectorNode ;



jssocket= new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/websocket/name?user_id="+ generateRandomInteger(0, 3));


jssocket.onopen = function(e) {

     console.log("[open] Connection established");
     
};

jssocket.onmessage = function(event) {
  console.log(`[message] Data received from server: ${event.data}`);
};

jssocket.onclose = function(event) {
  if (event.wasClean) {
      console.log(`[close] Connection closed cleanly, code=${event.code} reason=${event.reason}`);
  } else {
    // e.g. server process killed or network down
    // event.code is usually 1006 in this case
     console.log('[close] Connection died');
  }
};

jssocket.onerror = function(error) {
     console.log(`[error] ${error.message}`);
};


try {
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia
            || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia
            || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

    microphone = navigator.getUserMedia({
        audio : true,
        video : false
    }, onMicrophoneGranted, onMicrophoneDenied);
} catch (e) {
    alert(e)
}
async function onMicrophoneGranted(stream) {
    console.log(stream)
    


    context = new AudioContext();
    source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    
    await context.audioWorklet.addModule('/assets/js/buffer-detector.js');

    // Create our custom node.
    bufferDetectorNode= new AudioWorkletNode(context, 'buffer-detector');

    bufferDetectorNode.port.onmessage = (event) => {
        // Handling data from the processor.
        jssocket.send(event.data)
      // const byteArr = Int8Array.from(event.data)
    //const original = Array.from(byteArr)
      //  console.log(original);
      //  jssocket.send( Buffer.from(byteArr, 'base64').toString('utf8'));


        
      };
    
    source.connect(bufferDetectorNode);
    bufferDetectorNode.connect(context.destination);
     //source.connect(context.destination);
}

function _base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
    var binary_string = window.atob(base64);
    var len = binary_string.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes.buffer;
}
function onMicrophoneDenied() {
    console.log('denied')
}
function stop(){
    bufferDetectorNode.disconnect(context.destination)  
    source.disconnect(bufferDetectorNode)
}
function generateRandomInteger(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(min + Math.random() * (max - min + 1))
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

AudioWorklet

```
class BufferProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
    
  bufferSize = 256
  _bytesWritten = 0
  // 2. Create a buffer of fixed size
  _buffer = new Float32Array(this.bufferSize)
  
  
   initBuffer() {
    this._bytesWritten = 0
  }

  isBufferEmpty() {
    return this._bytesWritten === 0
  }

  isBufferFull() {
    return this._bytesWritten === this.bufferSize
  }
  
process (inputs) {
   
    this.append(inputs[0][0])

    return true;
  }


append(channelData) {
    if (this.isBufferFull()) {
      this.flush()
    }
    if (!channelData) return
    for (let i = 0; i < channelData.length; i++) {
      this._buffer[this._bytesWritten++] = channelData[i]
    }
  }
  
  
  flush() {
    // trim the buffer if ended prematurely
    this.port.postMessage(
      this._bytesWritten < this.bufferSize
        ? this._buffer.slice(0, this._bytesWritten)
        : this._buffer
    )
    this.initBuffer()
  }
  
  static get parameterDescriptors() {
    return [{
      name: 'Buffer Detector',
    }]
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this._socket = null;
    this._isRecording = true;
    this.initBuffer()

  }

  get socket() {
    return this._socket;
  }

  set socket(value) {
    if (value instanceof WebSocket) {
      this._socket = value;
    }
  }

  get recording() {
    return this._isRecording;
  }

  set recording(value) {
    if ('boolean' === typeof value) {
      this._isRecording = value;
    }
  }


}



registerProcessor('buffer-detector',BufferProcessor );
```

Comment: The data are probably corrupt. What format is it meant to be in?

Comment: streaming from micrphone , so expecting in raw pcm format. file is present here have a look https://file.io/D94taHwci1O4

Comment: fyi ffmpeg recognises 22 different pcm formats. I tried the likely candidates with your input file and they were found to be 'corrupt'

Comment: problem seems to be streaming from audio worklet

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know anything about your web tech

Comment: So, your Web Audio API samples are floating point, nominally between -1.0 and +1.0.  It seems you're mixing up the float32 array with the buffer that represents it, with a byte array that could represent that buffer.  You deleted all the files you uploaded, so I can't really help you there.  Just make sure that you're conscious of all the representations of data from end to end.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1spaCXsyVwClwPqSaZasE8qX4fSUNILUE/view?usp=sharing this is the file. Could you please help me with float32 array with the buffer. i wanted to implement text to speech. i dont unable to understand how to transform these float32 array what will be the audio encoding for it